# Autofac 4 Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler<TEvent>>> returns an empty list

Tags: c#, event-handling, autofac

I've been through tens of similar questions without finding the solution to my problem.
Therefore it could be an issue with Autofac 4, all the questions I found were related to previous versions.

I've got the following event publisher

```
public class EventPublisher : IEventPublisher
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _context;

    public EventPublisher(IComponentContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task Publish<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IEvent
    {
        if (@event == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(@event));
        }

        var eventHandlers = _context.Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler<TEvent>>>();

        foreach (IEventHandler<TEvent> handler in eventHandlers)
        {
            await handler.Handle(@event);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the services registration

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(SiteEventsHandler).Assembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IEventHandler<>));
```

Although the services have been registered correctly (I can see them in the registry) the resolve method returns an empty list.

**UPDATE**

The following is the command sender that calls the event publisher

```
public class CommandSender : ICommandSender
{
    private readonly IResolver _resolver;
    private readonly IEventPublisher _eventPublisher;

    public CommandSender(IResolver resolver, IEventPublisher eventPublisher)
    {
        _resolver = resolver;
        _eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }

    public void Send<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        if (command == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(command));
        }

        var commandHandler = _resolver.Resolve<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();

        if (commandHandler == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"No handler found for command '{command.GetType().FullName}'");
        }

        var events = commandHandler.Handle(command);

        foreach (var @event in events)
        {
            _eventPublisher.Publish(@event);
        }
    }
}
```

The command handler returns a list of domain events that have to be published.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Ah I understand now, you just need to construct the correct type to pass to Autofac. Try this in your EventPublisher class:

```
public async Task Publish<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IEvent
{
    if (@event == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(@event));
    }

    var handlerType = typeof (IEventHandler<>).MakeGenericType(@event.GetType());
    var handlerCollectionType = typeof (IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(handlerType);
    var eventHandlers = _context.Resolve(handlerCollectionType);

    foreach (IEventHandler<TEvent> handler in eventHandlers)
    {
        await handler.Handle(@event);
    }
}
```

**End update**

Are you sure the service registration is correct? It may be that the assembly you are registering is not correct:

```
typeof(SiteEventsHandler).Assembly
```

This is working for me with the following setup - an event interface & class:

```
public interface IEvent {}
public class MyEvent : IEvent {}
```

A service interface:

```
public interface IEventHandler<in T> where T : Event {}
```

And two implementations:

```
public class MyEventHandlerOne : IEventHandler<MyEvent> {}
public class MyEventHandlerTwo : IEventHandler<MyEvent> {}
```

Autofac is configured thusly:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (IEvent).Assembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof (IEventHandler<>))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerDependency();
_container = builder.Build();
```

Resolving the services gives a collection of 2:

```
var canResolve = CanResolve<MyEvent>(_container);

static bool CanResolve<T>(IComponentContext context) where T : IEvent
{
    var handlers = context.Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler<T>>>().ToList();
    return handlers.Any();
}
```

Edited after 34gl3's comment

Comment: It works because you are resolving with MyEvent and not with TEvent

Comment: This doesn't work either. I have updated the question adding the code that calls the event publisher. As you can see I cannot pass the specific type (MyEvent) as argument but only the generic one(TEvent).

Comment: I am also passing a generic type, as you can see in the CanResolve<T> method. What is the difference from your method Send<TCommand>(TCommand command)? At some point you will need to invoke your method with something like Send<MyCommand>(MyCommand instance), passing a specific type to a method with generic type constraint, just as I am doing.

Comment: The difference is there, I'm not calling the method with a specific type because a command can potentially returns multiple events as you can see in my command sender. But if there is no alternative I'll change my design.

Comment: Ah sorry I've just realised what you want to do - updated my answer. Hope that helps

Comment: That's great thanks but I need to cast it anyway to a concrete type otherwise I'll not be able to trigger the handle method. I cannot see a way out from this, I think I have to change the design.

Answer (score 0):

Use RegisterGeneric in your Composition Root to register IEventHandler<>

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components